# float CSS issue- windows 8-like tiles

Tags: css, windows, html

Here's my code:

```
<div style="background-color:red;border:2px solid red;height:100px;width:500px;float:left;margin-right:20px;margin-bottom:20px;"><center style="font-size:100px;">1</CENTER></div><div style="background-color:red;border:2px solid red;height:200px;width:500px;float:left;margin-right:20px;margin-bottom:20px;"><center style="font-size:100px;">2</CENTER></div>
<div style="background-color:red;border:2px solid red;height:100px;width:500px;float:left;margin-right:20px;margin-bottom:20px;position:relative;top:-100px;"><center style="font-size:100px;">3</CENTER></div>
```

Here's a screenie:
[image]

Yet the problem is I want it too look more like this (with the 3rd bad guy stacked under 1):
[image]

Comment: try floating 2 to the right and leaving 1 and 3 display:inline-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a need to float any of the DIV's. What you're after is the default behavior for an inline-block element.

```
display: inline-block;
```

I think you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4Rq6n/

Comment: what if they're different sizes

Comment: Could you be more specific? You can always change the size of the individual divs and it will continue to show as many blocks as will fit on the screen next to each other. I chose 50% in my example because I saw that you had two columns in your original post.

Comment: see for example my question was to fill them in regardless of size. for example http://jsfiddle.net/4Rq6n/2/ i would want the one below to fill in the one above's place, instead of a gap, see my original image

Comment: Ahhh... I see. Unfortunately, I do not think that it is possible to get that type of behavior with CSS alone. Here is a nice JavaScript library that does what I think you want and more:  http://gridster.net/

Comment: On second thought, provided that you know the number of columns that you want in advance, something like this could work: http://jsfiddle.net/4Rq6n/3/